# Pygame - Issues creating projectiles, "add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int"

Tags: pygame

I am creating an Asteroids type game using Pygame and am having trouble firing projectiles. I have a sprite group for the projectile object and some code to add the projectile.

```
if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
     projectiles.add(Projectile(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, player.direction))
```

Problem is when I press space in game to fire the projectile I get the error "add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int".

I have a very similar statement for adding asteroids when the game first starts without any issues so I'm not really sure what the problem is. I'll leave the rest of the code below. The add statement giving issues is in the main function near the bottom. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Import Modules
import pygame
import math
import random

#Movement Function
def calculate_new_xy(old_xy,speed,direction):
    new_x = old_xy[0] + (speed*math.cos(direction))
    new_y = old_xy[1] + (speed*math.sin(direction))
    return new_x, new_y

#Collision Function
def isColliding(x, y, xTo, yTo, size):
    if x > xTo - size and x < xTo + size and y > yTo - size and y < yTo + size:
        return True
    return False

#Draw Text Function
def drawText(msg, color, x, y, s, center=True):
    screen_text = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", s).render(msg, True, color)
    if center:
        rect = screen_text.get_rect()
        rect.center = (x, y-50)
    else:
        rect = (x, y)
    display.blit(screen_text, rect)

#Initialize Variables

#Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

#Display Height/Width
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

#Asteroid Class
class Asteroid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Initialize values
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0)):
        #Initialize sprite class
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #Asteroid sprite
        self.asteroid = pygame.image.load("asteroid.png").convert()
        self.image = self.asteroid
        #Rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        #Initialize random starting angle
        self.angle = random.randint(0, 360)
        #Asteroid random Speed
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 3)
        #Asteroid random direction
        self.direction = math.radians(random.randrange(0, 360, 3))

    #Update asteroid object
    def update(self):
        #Constantly rotate asteroid
        self.angle -= 3 % 360

        #Get image angle and position
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.asteroid, self.angle*-1)

        #Use rectangle to get center of image
        #Save ship's current center.
        x, y = self.rect.center
        #Replace old rect with new rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Put the new rect's center at old center.
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

        #Move Asteroid
        self.rect.center = calculate_new_xy(self.rect.center,self.speed,self.direction)

        #Screen Border
        #Moves the asteroid to the opposite side of the screen if they go outside the border
        if self.rect.x > display_width:
            self.rect.x = -20
        elif self.rect.x < -20:
            self.rect.x = display_width
        elif self.rect.y > display_height:
            self.rect.y = -20
        elif self.rect.y < -20:
            self.rect.y = display_height

#Projectile Class
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Initialize values
    def _init_(self,x,y,direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir = direction
        self.ttl = 30

    #Update projectile object
    def update(self):
        #Changing direction
        self.x += projectilespd * math.cos(self.direction)
        self.y += projectilespd * math.sin(self.direction)

        #Draw projectile
        pygame.draw.circle(display, white, (self.x,self.y),1)

        #Screen Border
        if self.x > display_width:
            self.x = 0
        elif self.x < 0:
            self.x = display_width
        elif self.y > display_height:
            self.y = 0
        elif self.y < 0:
            self.y = display_height
        self.ttl -= 1        

#Player Class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Initialize ship sprite, angle lines, and rectangle
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0), size=(200, 200)):
        #Player sprite
        self.ship = pygame.image.load("ship.png").convert()
        self.image = self.ship
        #Rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        #Initialize angle
        self.angle = 0
        #Initialize direction
        self.direction = 0

    #Update player object
    def update(self):
        #Rotation
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: self.angle -= 3 % 360
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.angle += 3 % 360

        #Get image angle and position
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.ship, self.angle*-1)

        #Use rectangle to get center of image
        #Save ship's current center.
        x, y = self.rect.center
        #Replace old rect with new rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Put the new rect's center at old center.
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

        #Convert angle to radians
        self.direction = math.radians(self.angle-90)

        #Increase speed if Up is pressed
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: self.speed = 5
        else: self.speed = 0

        #Move Ship
        self.rect.center = calculate_new_xy(self.rect.center,self.speed,self.direction)

        #Screen Border
        #Moves the player to the opposite side of the screen if they go outside the border
        if self.rect.x > display_width:
            self.rect.x = -50
        elif self.rect.x < -50:
            self.rect.x = display_width
        elif self.rect.y > display_height:
            self.rect.y = -50
        elif self.rect.y < -50:
            self.rect.y = display_height

#Main Function
def main(gameState):
    #Player starting position
    player = Player(pos=(400, 300))
    #Asteroid group
    asteroids = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #Projectile group
    projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()

    #Create asteroids
    for x in range(8):
        asteroids.add(Asteroid(pos=(100 + (x*120), 100 + (x*20))))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #closes game
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
        #Game Menu
        while gameState == "Menu":
            #Fill background
            display.fill((0,0,0))
            #Display menu text
            drawText("ASTEROIDS", white, display_width / 2, display_height / 2, 150)
            drawText("Press any key to START", white, display_width / 2, display_height / 2 + 120, 40)
            #Check game start or end
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    gameState = "Playing"
            pygame.display.update()
            #Low frame rate for menu
            clock.tick(5)

        #Get key inputs
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        #Fill background
        display.fill(black)

        #Check for player collision with asteroid
        for asteroid in asteroids:
            if gameState != "Game Over":
                if isColliding(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, asteroid.rect.x, asteroid.rect.y, 30):
                    gameState = "Game Over"

        #Update and draw player if not game over
        if gameState != "Game Over":
            #Update player
            player.update()
            #Draw player
            display.blit(player.image, player.rect)

        #Update asteroids
        asteroids.update()

        #Draw asteroids
        asteroids.draw(display)

        #Fire Projectiles
        if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            projectiles.add(Projectile(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, player.direction))

        #Update projectiles
        projectiles.update()

        #Draw projectiles
        projectiles.draw(display)

        #Display Game Over and restart option
        if gameState == "Game Over":
            drawText("GAME OVER", white, display_width / 2, display_height / 2, 150)
            drawText("Press R to restart", white, display_width / 2, display_height / 2 + 120, 40)
            if pressed[pygame.K_r]: 
                main(gameState = "Playing")

        #Makes updates to the game screen
        pygame.display.update()

        #Frame rate
        clock.tick(60)

#Initialize Game
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #initialize pygame
    pygame.init()

    #initialize display settings
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Asteroids')

    #initialize game clock
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #start main function
    main(gameState = "Menu")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the [`pygame.sprite.Group.add`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) operation, but the obejct you want to add is not a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object, because the object is not constructed at all.
You missed to the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) call in the constructor of `Projectile`. Furthermore the name of the constructor has to be [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) rather `_init_`:

```py
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Initialize values
    def __init__(self,x,y,direction):
        super.__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir = direction
        self.ttl = 30
```